# Is GCC (Google Congestion Control) implemented in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

I was doing some reading on GCC (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rmcat-gcc-02) but was unable to find if this was actually implemented in WebRTC.

Would someone be able to verify or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is implemented here:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/webrtc/modules/congestion_controller/?q=congestion_controller

The details have changed a bit since the draft was written but you'll find many of the elements described here in the goog_cc directory.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK yes, it was used in WebRTC. Search for REMB in WebRTC.

Currently transport wide congestion control is considered a better approach. See please this blog post for details http://www.rtcbits.com/2017/01/bandwidth-estimation-in-webrtc-and-new.html